# How can I do nested for loop in jsonnet and access the variables?

Tags: prometheus-operator, jsonnet

How can I access `t`, which is the thing I get from the outer loop?

```
{
  ['applications-' + name + t]: kp.applications[name][t]
  for name in [t for t in std.objectFields(kp.applications)]
}
```

My array looks something like this:

```
applications :
    alertmanager-bot: { 
        deployment: {...},
        service: {...},
    go-import-redirector: {
        deployment: {...},
        service: {...},
```

I want to loop over all the deployments/services and put them in separate keys in order to get them into separate files.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working with:

```
{
  ['applications-' + appname + '-' + kind]: kp.applications[appname][kind]
  for appname in std.objectFields(kp.applications)
  for kind in std.objectFields(kp.applications[appname])
}
```

I had misunderstood the order of the for loops.